# Alice and Bob, are a part of a group of 6 people who have all placed their hats on a table...

Tags: probability

What is the probability that at least one, either Alice or Bob, will get his own hat?

I'm a little stuck trying to answer this question and wondering what formula I should apply?

Should I first work out the probability that neither of the two get their own hats?

Comment: Yeah, work out $1-P(\text{neither gets their hat back})$

Comment: @user1001001 so assume Alice picks first she has a 5/6 chance of picking the wrong hat. Then Bob has a 4/5 chance of picking the wrong hat. Unless Alice picked bob's hat, then bob has a 5/5 chance of picking the wrong hat. I'm not sure how I should add accumulate these together to form P(neither)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is small enough that you can also calculate it directly.

- There are $4!=24$ ways in which Alice and Bob can both get their own hats back, since the other $4$ hats can be permuted arbitrarily amongst their owners.
- There are $4\cdot4!=96$ ways in which Alice can get her own hat back while Bob gets someone else’s hat: there are $4$ possibilities for the hat the Bob gets, since he cannot get Alice’s or his own, and the remaining $4$ hats can again be permuted arbitrarily amongst the other $4$ people.
- Clearly there are also $4\cdot4!=96$ ways in which Bob can get his own hat back while Alice gets someone else’s hat.

Thus, there are $216$ ways in which at least one of the two gets his or her own hat back, and the probability of this is

$$\frac{216}{6!}=\frac{216}{720}=\frac3{10}\,.$$

Comment: But what if Alice or Bob choices the others hat in the first scenario? Although the rest of the hats have been given to the other 4, there's still 50/50 that Alice could take Bobs hat? Meaning there wouldn't be 24 ways?

Comment: @DamLk: No: the $4!$ figure is based on the assumption that Alice and Bob got their own hats. There are another $4!$ arrangments in which Bob gets Alice’s hat and Alice gets Bob’s. Perhaps you’d be more comfortable thinking of it as $1\cdot1\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$: there’s one chocie for the hat that Alice gets — her own — one for the hat that Bob gets — his own — $4$ for the hat that the next person gets, and so on.